# Importing styles in angular.json vs importing in styles.css?

Tags: css, angular, build

What is the difference between importing styles in angular.json and importing in styles.css?

**Importing in angular.json**

[image]

**Importing in styles.css**

[image]

Hope to have explained my question well. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

The `styles` array inside of the `angular.json` file is used to declare global styles for a project (`styles.css` being one).

If you import all of your other stylesheets into `styles.css` (and `styles.css` is specified in the `styles` array in `angular.json`), you'll end up with one global, composite stylesheet.

If you put all of your stylesheets into the `angular.json` `styles` array independently (rather than importing them into `styles.css`), you'll end up with multiple global stylesheets.

Answer (score 5):

In `angular.json`
The styles.css file allows users to add global styles and supports CSS imports.
You can add more global styles via the styles option inside your project's build target options in `angular.json`. These will be loaded exactly as if you had added them in a `<link>` tag inside `index.html`.

Importing css files in `styles.css` enable you divide your css code into separate files for the sake of organize code

for more information about global styles, follow this [link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-styles)